# na.locf - Negative length vectors are not allowed

Tags: r

I am trying carry forward non-na values until reaching the next non-na with the following code:

```
test3 <- data.table(final_data)

test3 <- test3[, na.locf(test3, na.rm = F, fromLast = F, maxgap = Inf), by = "gvkey"]
```

It works when I don't include the ... by = gvkey] part.
However, I need the code to stop when reaching a new gvkey, bc otherwise it would carry forward wrong company data. I got it in long format (example below). As you can see, what happens if i don't use ...by = gvkey], it carries the value of gvkey1 over to gvkey2, which I want to avoid. But when doing so, I receive the following error message:

> ```
> Error in `[.data.table`(test3, , na.locf(test3, na.rm = F, fromLast = F,  : 
>   negative length vectors are not allowed
> ```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>date</th><th>gvkey</th><th>dlcq</th><th>dlttq</th></tr><tr><td>date1</td><td>gvkey1</td><td>10</td><td>20</td></tr><tr><td>date2</td><td>gvkey1</td><td>NA</td><td>NA</td></tr><tr><td>date3</td><td>gvkey1</td><td>NA</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>.</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>.</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>.</td><td> </td><td> </td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>date10</td><td>gvkey2</td><td>NA</td><td>NA</td></tr><tr><td>date11</td><td>gvkey2</td><td>10</td><td>NA</td></tr><tr><td>date12</td><td>gvkey2</td><td>NA</td><td>NA</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Any suggestions/solutions very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table::nafill()` from the lastest development release (v1.12.3) form data.table

```
DT <- fread("date | gvkey | dlcq | dlttq
            date1 | gvkey1 | 10 | 20
            date2 | gvkey1 | NA | NA 
            date3 | gvkey1 | NA | 10 
            date10 | gvkey2 | NA | NA 
            date11 | gvkey2 | 10 | NA 
            date12 | gvkey2 | NA | NA")

cols = c("dlcq", "dlttq")
DT[, (cols) := lapply( .SD, nafill, type = "locf" ), by = gvkey, .SDcols = cols][]

#      date  gvkey dlcq dlttq
# 1:  date1 gvkey1   10    20
# 2:  date2 gvkey1   10    20
# 3:  date3 gvkey1   10    10
# 4: date10 gvkey2   NA    NA
# 5: date11 gvkey2   10    NA
# 6: date12 gvkey2   10    NA
```

see: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation for instructions about loading the dev-version.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end I don't get any error messages:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

test3[, na.locf(test3, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, maxgap = Inf), by = "gvkey"]
```

giving this which has no errors although it is not the desired answer.

```
     gvkey   date  gvkey dlcq dlttq
 1: gvkey1  date1 gvkey1   10    20
 2: gvkey1  date2 gvkey1   10    20
 3: gvkey1  date3 gvkey1   10    10
 4: gvkey1 date10 gvkey2   10    10
 5: gvkey1 date11 gvkey2   10    10
 6: gvkey1 date12 gvkey2   10    10
 7: gvkey2  date1 gvkey1   10    20
 8: gvkey2  date2 gvkey1   10    20
 9: gvkey2  date3 gvkey1   10    10
10: gvkey2 date10 gvkey2   10    10
11: gvkey2 date11 gvkey2   10    10
12: gvkey2 date12 gvkey2   10    10
```

The problem is that the correct way to refer to `test3` within `test3` is to use `.SD` like this:

```
test3[, na.locf(.SD, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, maxgap = Inf), by = "gvkey"]
```

giving:

```
    gvkey   date dlcq dlttq
1: gvkey1  date1   10    20
2: gvkey1  date2   10    20
3: gvkey1  date3   10    10
4: gvkey2 date10   NA    NA
5: gvkey2 date11   10    NA
6: gvkey2 date12   10    NA
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "
date | gvkey | dlcq | dlttq
date1 | gvkey1 | 10 | 20
date2 | gvkey1 | NA | NA 
date3 | gvkey1 | NA | 10 
date10 | gvkey2 | NA | NA 
date11 | gvkey2 | 10 | NA 
date12 | gvkey2 | NA | NA"


library(data.table)
test3 <- fread(Lines)
```

Comment: Could it be because there might be groups with only one `NA` entry? I mean only one entry and that would be NA

Comment: Have expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks! I tried test3[, na.locf(.SD, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE, maxgap = Inf), by = "gvkey"] and it does not give me the error msg. I have to double check, since my set has ~90mn rows, but it looks good.